# .Net Core 2.2 Web API Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-core-2.2

I have the following controller which I wanted to use as an Web API Controller for ajax posts to retrieve data from my user table.

```
namespace MyProjectName.Controllers.API
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly myContext _context;
        public UsersController(myContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public List<string> GetInstitutionNamesById(int id)
        {
            // returns desired list
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'd expect the routing of this Function to be like this: **/api/users/getinstitutionnamesbyid** but apparently it seems to be just **/api/users** which I find really confusing (what if I add additional HttpGet Functions?).

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong? Am I using Web Api Controllers not the Intended way? Is my routing wrong?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i agree that naming in api's are confusing. but i think the point of api's are that the name of the controller is what you are expecting to get from it, so you really only have one get operation(and the name of the method is not relevant other than "get") or else if would be even more confusing. you need to write another controller for other get operations. but you also have the overloaded option with getting specific number like: /api/users/3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> `[Route("api/[controller]")]`

With this template, you're explicitly stating that you only care about the name of the controller. In your example, `GetInstitutionNamesById` is the name of the *action*, which isn't being considered by the template.

There are a few options for achieving what you're asking for here:

1. Change your `[Route]` template to include the action name:

   ```
   [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
   ```

   This option applies to all actions within your controller.
2. Change the `HttpGet` constraint attribute to specify the action *implicitly*:

   ```
   [HttpGet("[action]")]
   ```

   This option ensures that the name of your action method will always be used as the route 
   segment.
3. Change the `HttpGet` constraint attribute to specify the action *explicitly*:

   ```
   [HttpGet("GetInstitutionNamesById")]
   ```

   This option allows you to use a route segment that differs from the name of the action method itself.

In terms of whether you're using routing in the correct way here - that's somewhat opinion-based. Generally, you'll see that APIs are attempting to be RESTful, using route templates that match resources, etc. With this approach, you might have something more like the following:

```
/api/Users/{userId}/InstitutionNames
```

In this case, you might have a separate `InstitutionNames` controller or you might bundle it up into the `Users` controller. There really are many ways to do this, but I won't go into any more on that here as it's a little off-topic and opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to name it this way

```
    [HttpGet("[action]/{id}")]
    public List<string> GetInstitutionNamesById(int id)
    {
        // returns desired list
    }
```

and from ajax call /api/users/GetInstitutionNamesById/1